# How to get MAX value of the result returned by a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014.

I need to send the result of the following query to a client application:

```
SELECT PrimaryKeyID, ColA, ColB, ColC , CreateDate 
FROM VeryHeavyView 
WHERE Condtion<123
```

I need to record `Max(PrimaryKeyID)` and `Max(CreateDate)` into a log tables.

I like to do it with overhead. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

**Update 1**

Below are a few ideas how to do this, but I thought I post question here and see if there is a better or more efficient way of doing this:

- I can simply do this by querying twice, but that is not efficient
- I know that I can store the result into a temp table and SELECT MAX the temp table
- I can group by all the columns. That is very costly since the actual query I m using is quite expensive with 3000 rows result.
- I can do query like `SELECT @Var1=PrimaryKeyID, ColA, ColB, ColC , @Var2=CreateDate FROM VeryHeavyView  ORDER BY PrimaryKeyID`, but I am not sure if it is supported

Answer (score 1):

You can write your query and a query that calculates the two maxima you want as common table expressions, and then cross join the two together.

```
WITH
q AS (
    SELECT PrimaryKeyID, ColA, ColB, ColC , CreateDate 
    FROM VeryHeavyView 
    WHERE Condtion<123
),
m AS (
    SELECT max( PrimaryKeyID ) AS max_id,
           max( CreateDate ) AS max_create_date
    FROM q
)

SELECT q.*, m.*
FROM q CROSS JOIN m
```

Since the second CTE (m) should return only one row, this will just affix max_id and max_create_date columns to the right of your result (with the same values on every row).

Comment: @Erc: This approach repeats the max columns to every single row of the result set. Is there any way to break this to two result sets?

Comment: Sort of. Instead of a cross join, you could use a full outer join with `ON false`, which would give you

Comment: (Sorry. I hit Enter too soon, and for some reason I can't edit the previous comment.) Instead of `FROM q CROSS JOIN m`, you could use `q FULL OUTER JOIN m On false`. You would still have the two additional columns, but in the rows that come from your primary query, the max columns would be empty, and there would be one extra row at the end that would have data *only* in the max columns (the other columns—PrimaryKeyID, ColA, etc.—would be empty).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way we can assign a variable inside the m query in the CTE? I think we are close here. When I tried I get "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations." error. There should be a hack to help us.

Answer (score 0):

You may need window aggregate function

```
SELECT Max(PrimaryKeyID) over (order by PrimaryKeyID desc),
, ColA, ColB, ColC , 
Max(CreateDate) over (order by CreateDate desc)
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE Condtion<123
```

You may study more [here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1)

Comment: This way, I have the MaxValue(s) 3000 times repeated in the resultset. It would be heavy on the network and potentially memory of the client application.

Comment: Add a wrapper query around this query and select only max values with distinct. run the query and see the result don't assume about the performance in advane

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, if you are doing this in a stored procedure, you can run a query to get your max values and execute the same query to get all of the max values and you won't really add any time to the the execution time, assuming the query plan gets cached.

Running these 2 queries in succession really *could* be the same amount of time as just running one of them, but give you 2 results.

```
SELECT max(PrimaryKeyID) MaxPrimaryKeyID, max(CreateDate) MaxCreateDate    
FROM VeryHeavyView 
WHERE Condtion < 123

SELECT PrimaryKeyID, ColA, ColB, ColC , CreateDate 
FROM VeryHeavyView 
WHERE Condtion < 123
```